# Dynamics CRM Script Help - Date Field Comparison to Current Date + Number Field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, jscript

Order form has two fields, Ship Date (datefield) and Lead Time (number field in days).

When a ship date is entered, it should be greater than the current date + the lead time. alert user if not, and do not allow save of record.

- There is one exception to the rule though: If the approved for rush field and approved by field is filled out the alert is not necessary and record can be saved.

++ It would be a plus if this could actually not account for weekend days. But not mandatory

```
function checkLeadTime
{
var shipDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("requestdeliveryby").getValue();
var leadTime = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("orbus_leadtime").getValue();
var leadTimeDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("orbus_leadtimedate").getValue():

if(leadTime != NULL)
{

var approvedRushProduction = xrm.getAttribute("orbus_projectapprovedrush").getValue();
var approvedBy = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("orbus_approvedbyid").getValue();
var currentTime = new Date();
var newDate = currentTime.setDays(currentTime.getDays + leadTime);
leadTimeDate.setValue(newDate);

if(approvedRushProduction == 0 && approvedBy == NULL)
 {
 if ( newDate < shipDate)
  {
    alert("Sorry, Ship Date is less than lead time!");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Current Time = " + newDate);
  }
 }
```

}
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your function to the form onSave event.

```
if ( newDate < shipDate ) {
    alert("Sorry, Ship Date is less than lead time!");
    Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
} else {
    alert("Current Time = " + newDate);
}
```

Use Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs().preventDefault() to stop the save event.

Answer (score 0):

To stop saving and show error message you can use:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(fieldName).setNotification(message);
```

http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/10/17/crm-2013-new-features-javascript-notifications/